# Geometric corrispondence of the following ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ be polynomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and let $x \in V(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ a point in $k^n$. Called $I$ the ideal generated by $f_1,\ldots,f_m$, define
$$J:=\{ g \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] : \exists h \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \text{ such that } h(x)\ne 0 \text{ and } gh \in I\}.$$
Is there any geometric meaning associated to the ideal $J$? I think it's something related to the hypersurface $h$ and that $x$ doesn't lie on $h$, but I can't recompose all the pieces in my hand.

Thanks a lot for any explanation/hint/reference.

Comment: $J$ would be $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ since you can always use an $h\in I$.

Comment: @KittyL : $h$ can't be chosen in $I$ since $h(x) \neq 0$ by hypothesis.

Comment: I see. Sorry, didn't see the (x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=V(I)$ and assume that $k$ is algebraically closed and that $I=\sqrt I$.
Call $X_x$  the union of all irreducible components of $X$ containing $x$ and $X_x^c$ the union of all irreducible components of $X$ not containing $x$.

> **Geometric meaning of $J: \quad$**  $J=i(X_x)$, the ideal of polynomials vanishing on $X_x$.

Indeed, to prove that $i(X_x)\subset J$ it suffices to remark that there exists a polynomial $h_0\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] $ such that $h_0(x)=1$ and $h_0(y)=0$ for all $y\in X_x^c$.
And to  prove that  $J\subset i(X_x)$ it suffices to notice that since $gh$ vanishes on any irreducible component $X_l$ of $X$ containing $x$,  $g$ will vanish on the open dense subset of $X_l$ where $h\neq0$, hence on all of $X_l$.